# Convert the column values into rows in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

input data :

```
    select '543318' as ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '543318' as SUBSCRIBER_ID ,'Active' as status,'20021' as id1,'20021' as id2,'20021' as id3 from dual
union all
select '9900' as ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '963421' as SUBSCRIBER_ID ,'Active' as status,'20021' as id1,'11' as id2,'41' as id3 from dual
union all
select '7089' as ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '673456' as SUBSCRIBER_ID ,'Active' as status,'11' as id1,'0' as id2,'0' as id3 from dual
union all
select '8909' as ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '785643' as SUBSCRIBER_ID ,'Active' as status,'20021' as id1,'43' as id2,'0' as id3 from dual;
```

output:

```
    select '543318' as ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '543318' as SUBSCRIBER_ID ,'Active' as status,'20021' as id1 from dual
    union all
    select '9900' as ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '963421' as SUBSCRIBER_ID ,'Active' as status,'20021' as id1  from dual
    union all
    select '9900' as ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '963421' as SUBSCRIBER_ID ,'Active' as status,'41' as id1 from dual
    union all
    select '9900' as ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '963421' as SUBSCRIBER_ID ,'Active' as status,'11' as id1  from dual
    union all
    select '7089' as ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '673456' as SUBSCRIBER_ID ,'Active' as status,'11' as id1 from dual
    union all
    select '8909' as ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '785643' as SUBSCRIBER_ID ,'Active' as status,'20021' as id1 from dual
    union all
    select '8909' as ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '785643' as SUBSCRIBER_ID ,'Active' as status,'43' as id1 from dual;
```

I tried to combine id1, id2,id3 columns into a single comma separated column and then use regexp_substr expression to split the values.

```
with rws as (
   select '20021,11,41' as str from dual
)
  select 
  regexp_substr (
           str,
           '[^,]+',
           1,
           level
         ) value
  from   rws
  connect by level <= 
    length ( str ) - length ( replace ( str, ',' ) ) + 1;
```

There are around 1.6 million records and its taking too long to return results and also if there is 0 in id columns, its returning more than one row.

Any suggestions on how I can improve the performance or please suggest any other way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a serie of `UNION` to unpivot your data :

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SUBSCRIBER_ID, STATUS, ID1
FROM mytable
WHERE ID1 <> 0
UNION
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SUBSCRIBER_ID, STATUS, ID2 AS ID1
FROM mytable
WHERE ID2 <> 0
UNION
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SUBSCRIBER_ID, STATUS, ID3 AS ID1
FROM mytable
WHERE ID3 <> 0
ORDER BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qt-r_xzO)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`OUTER APPLY`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1) join if your version of Oracle supports it.

```
select
  T.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
  T.SUBSCRIBER_ID,
  T.status,
  L.id1
from T
outer apply (select T.id1 from dual where T.id1 != '0' union
             select T.id2 from dual where T.id2 != '0' union
             select T.id3 from dual where T.id3 != '0') L;
```

Results:

```
+----------------+---------------+--------+-------+
| ACCOUNT_NUMBER | SUBSCRIBER_ID | STATUS |  ID1  |
+----------------+---------------+--------+-------+
|         543318 |        543318 | Active | 20021 |
|           9900 |        963421 | Active | 11    |
|           9900 |        963421 | Active | 20021 |
|           9900 |        963421 | Active | 41    |
|           7089 |        673456 | Active | 11    |
|           8909 |        785643 | Active | 20021 |
|           8909 |        785643 | Active | 43    |
|          17042 |        124816 | Active | null  |
+----------------+---------------+--------+-------+
```

Try it on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LZhXCMOA).

Answer (score 1):

You can `UNPIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT account_number,
       subscriber_id,
       status,
       id1
FROM   table_name
       UNPIVOT (id1 FOR type IN (id1, id2, id3))
WHERE  id1 <> '0';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (account_number, subscriber_id, status, id1, id2, id3) AS
  SELECT '543318', '543318', 'Active', '20021', '20021', '20021' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '9900',   '963421', 'Active', '20021', '11',    '41'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '7089',   '673456', 'Active', '11',    '0',     '0'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '8909',   '785643', 'Active', '20021', '43',    '0'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '17042',  '124816', 'Active', '0',     '0',     '0'     FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ACCOUNT_NUMBER | SUBSCRIBER_ID | STATUS | ID1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 543318 | 543318 | Active | 20021 |
| 543318 | 543318 | Active | 20021 |
| 543318 | 543318 | Active | 20021 |
| 9900 | 963421 | Active | 20021 |
| 9900 | 963421 | Active | 11 |
| 9900 | 963421 | Active | 41 |
| 7089 | 673456 | Active | 11 |
| 8909 | 785643 | Active | 20021 |
| 8909 | 785643 | Active | 43 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YNIzUzyI)